# GraphQL: Apollo Server subscription with namespace

Tags: apollo-server

I know it's somehow best practice to keep mutations and subscription on top-level and not introduce namespace types.

But anyway I would be interested how a subscription with a namespace could be implemented in Apollo Server.

For example the following case:

```
type Subscription {
  imageAPI: ImageAPISubscriptions!
  contentAPI: ContentAPISubscriptions!
}

type ImageAPISubscriptions {
  subscribeImageChanges(imageId: ID!): ImageChanges!
}

...
```

Now apollo complains that in the resolver for this subscription, the top-level function e.g. `imageAPI` doesn't return an AsyncIterator because this happens in the nested `subscribeImageChanges` function.

How can this be technically solved?

I'm using apollo-server-express 2.4.8.

Comment: Aenderi any updates on this topic from your side? I asking it because I also need namespaces but I see no solution

Comment: @YuriyGyerts No, I think it's not possible (and would also be not a good idea) because in theory the API would allow you to call multiple subscriptions at once.

Comment: Almost 4 years later, here I'm looking for a solution to the same problem.
@ChristofAenderl, How did you solve this issue?
For mutations and queries this pattern works, but for subscription not.